# TU-local entity definition contains a recursive reference to itself

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards

I think the following 2 paragraphs of the standard recursively reference each other. Is it a defect or am I missing something?

https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#14

> A declaration is an exposure if it either names a TU-local entity
> (defined below), ignoring
>
> - ...
>
> or defines a constexpr variable initialized to a TU-local value
> (defined below).

https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#15

> An entity is TU-local if it is
>
> - ...
> - a specialization of a template whose (possibly instantiated) declaration is an exposure.

The definition of a *TU-local value* is based on the definition of a *TU-local entity* too.

Comment: Note the `"or" given in [basic.link#14]. This means there are 2 choices for a declaration to be an exposure. First it can be a TU-local entity and second choice is if it defines a constexpr variable initialized to a TU-local value.

Comment: @JasonLiam yeah, but a TU-local value is based on a TU-local entity too as noted at the end of the question (according to https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#16).

Comment: Note that "whose" refers to the template declaration, not the specialization. That is, a specialization is TU-local if the template declaration is an exposure.

Comment: @molbdnilo agree, but I don't think it eliminates the recursiveness.

Comment: There are plenty of recursive definitions in the standard; nothing wrong with that. E.g. `expression` is defined as either `assignment-expression` or `expression , assignment-expression`. And if you follow the chain of definitions from `assignment-expression`, `expression` appears as a leaf on some branches.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it's ok in [the formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Recursive_grammars). Please provide an example of your last statement in C++. I don't think you can have a pure `expression` as a leaf.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik in formal grammars `expression -> assignment-expression | expression , assignment-expression` doesn't mean `expression` **is** (defined as) `X | Y`. It's the other way around: `assignment-expression` **is** an `expression` and `expression, assignment-expression` **is** an `expression` too. So there are many sub-expressions (id, mul, add, etc.) that are expressions, but there should be no rule `expression -> expression`.

Comment: Neither is there in your question a rule that `TU-local entity -> TU-local entity`. The part of p15 you quote talks about a specialization of a template, in terms of the primary template it's a specialization of. Since a primary template is not a specialization, considering whether a template declaration is an exposure won't take you down the same path in p15.